# How to change a matrix's dimension without using reshape in Python

Tags: python, numpy, shapes

Below is the matrix of (3*3)

```
a_matrix=np.array([[2,3,5],[3,2,7],[1,4,2]])
```

and i want to change it to (9*1) which is

```
[[2],[3],[5],[3],[2],[7],[1],[4],[2]]
```

The problem is that i need to do this without using reshape method in numpy. BTW, below is what i did which is kind of wrong. Could anyone help me with that? BTW, **i can't use those pre-defined methods to do it, i have to implement it by my own method. **.Any help is appreciated!!!

```
import numpy as np   
a_list=[]
a_matrix=np.array([[2,3,5],[3,2,7],[1,4,2]]) #3*3 matrix
for i in range(3):
   a_list.extend(a_matrix[i,:])
a_list=np.asarray(a_list) #To convert the list to numpy array
print(a_list.T.shape) #To print the shape of transpose
```

**--->(9,) # I want (9,1) not (9,)**

Comment: Reahape is such a fundamental method in numpy, that it is hard to know what you are allowed to use.  Also we shouldn't be helping you with assignments that are supposed to test your knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.ravel` and add a dummy axis afterwards.

```
l_list = a_matrix.ravel()[:,None]
```

EDIT:
If you want a numpy-free method:

```
l_list = []
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        # replace [i][j] with [i,j] if a_matrix
        # is allowed to be a numpy array
        l_list.append([a_matrix[i][j]])
```

If you want to have the result as a numpy array without using `ravel` or `reshape`, you could create the output array in advance

```
l_list = np.empty((9,1))
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        # replace [i][j] with [i,j] if a_matrix
        # is allowed to be a numpy array
        l_list[i*3 + j] = a_matrix[i][j]
```

Comment: It's just i am doing an assignment, and we are not allowed to use those methods, we have to define our own methods.

Answer (score 1):

Flatten it and use a list comprehension

```
result = np.array([[x] for x in a_matrix.ravel()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer where you code the solution yourself (as per your assignments requirements).

```
import numpy as np

a_matrix = np.array([[2,3,5],[3,2,7],[1,4,2]])

a_list = [[elem] for row in a_matrix for elem in row]

a_list = np.asarray(a_list) 
print(a_list.T.shape)
```

Output should be as expected.

Comment: If he isn't allowed to use `reshape`, surely he can't use `transpose` either!  `a_list` when turned into an array is shape (1,9).

Answer (score 0):

A pure list operation:

```
In [122]: alist = [[2,3,5],[3,2,7],[1,4,2]]
In [123]: [[i] for x in alist for i in x]
Out[123]: [[2], [3], [5], [3], [2], [7], [1], [4], [2]]
```

Forget about the `np.array` stuff before or after.  If you can't use `reshape` there's no point in talking about `numpy`.  `shape` is an integral part of a numpy array, and changing it with `reshape` is a fundamental operation.